# Regular Expression for Feedback Answer More Than 10 Word (Google Form)

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am trying to create a feedback form which is accept answer for who write **more than 10 word** using data validation in Google Form. The only option I see is character count.

**Example of feedback form question:**
Suggestion to improve our courses? Please write more than 10 word.

**Example of feedback form answer:**
The course is very informative but it can be more helpful if the speaker give several quiz to know if the student understand or not. (More than 10 word count)

From the example above, I want to expect the respondent respond for than 10 word in that feedback form.
Hopping somebody to help me since I am not a programmer but I can understand some basic regular expression. Thanks.

Comment: Average English word is ~5 characters. You could write a regex or just require 6n characters, where n is the number of words you want. Even 5n would probably be okay (the example you gave has 10 words in the first 50 characters)

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am already found the right answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a space after every word and symbol.

```
([^ ]+( |$)){11,}
```

Comment: thanks! working perfectly in my feedback form.

Comment: `there are twelve words in this  and yet it does not match`

Comment: @jhbc The assumption had been stated in my answer.